# Different behaviour between Join and SelectMany after replacing one of the sets

Tags: join, linq

I hope that someone can shed a light on the (to me) unexpected behavioral difference between the two (result wise) equal queries.
A small program can be worth a thousand words, so here goes :

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
  var l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };  
  var l2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };  

  var q1 =  // or var q1 = l1.Join(l2, i => i, j => j, (i, j) => i);
      from i in l1  
      join j in l2
      on i equals j
      select i; 

  var q2 = //or var q2 = l1.SelectMany(i => l2.Where(j => i == j));  
      from i in l1
      from j in l2
      where i == j
      select i;

  var a1 = q1.ToList(); // 2 and 3, as expected
  var a2 = q2.ToList(); // 2 and 3, as expected

  l2.Remove(2);

  var b1 = q1.ToList(); // only 3, as expected  
  var b2 = q2.ToList(); // only 3, as expected

  // now here goes, lets replace l2 alltogether.   
  // Afterwards, I expected the same result as q1 delivered...  

  l2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };

  var c1 = q1.ToList(); // only 3 ? Still using the previous reference to l2 ?  
  var c2 = q2.ToList();  // 2 and 3, as expected  
}
```

Now I know that Join internally uses a lookup class to optimize performance, and without too much knowledge, my guess is that the combination of that with captured variables might cause this behavior, but to say I really understand it, no :-)
Is this an example of what Joel calls "a leaky abstraction" ?

Cheers,
Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually nearly there, given your query expansions in the comments:

```
var q1 = l1.Join(l2, i => i, j => j, (i, j) => i);

var q2 = l1.SelectMany(i => l2.Where(j => i == j));
```

Look at where `l2` is used in each case. In the `Join` case, the *value of `l2`* is passed into the method immediately. (Remember that the value is a reference to the list though... changing the contents of the list isn't the same as changing the value of `l2`.) Changing the value of `l2` later doesn't affect what the query returned by the `Join` method remembers.

Now look at `SelectManay`: `l2` is only used in the lambda expression... so it's a *captured variable*. That means that whenever the lambda expression is evaluated, the value of `l2` *at that moment in time* is used... so it will reflect any changes to the value.